# Kendo ui grid with custom filter

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo-ui grid and I want to create a totally custom column filter. Is there a way to pass a template or something like this to the grid?

**EDIT:**

Another question: is there a way to catch the click on "filter" button inside the filter view?

Comment: See their documentation: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/filter-menu-customization.html

Comment: Yes I saw that - none of the filters there are really custom. You can only manipulate the element you're getting in the filter function you provide. But what if for example I want my filter to have alist of checkboxes and that's all (and also without the dropdown saying "starts with", "equal to" etc.)

Comment: It doesn't seem like that functionality is supported in the current version of Kendo UI. You would have to roll your own filter widget and "attach" it to the grid.

Comment: I would use the header template of the column definition, for setting the HTML of the new column filter. at least a placeholder. After the grid is rendered, and the HTML is in place, I would attach all the event handlers to the awesome column filter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [filterMenuInit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-filterMenuInit) event of the Grid to attach a click handler to the "Clear"
and "filter" button.

for Clear button in

```
function filterMenuInit(e) {
    e.container.on("click", "[type='reset']", function () {
        alert("Clear button clicked");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that helped. Whoever is interested here is an example: http://jsbin.com/aPeBewe/1/edit

Comment: filterMenuInit is not triggered when setting "columnMenu: true", any ideas?